# Resizable DIV expanding in the wrong direction

Tags: html, css

I have a Web application containing a simple pop menu implemented as a resizable div.

The application must support both LTR and RTL languages.

When using a LTR language (e.g. English), the small indication for the resize appears at the lower-right corner of the div and, when dragging it, the div expands following the movement of the mouse.

When the application is used with a RTL language, the small indication appears at the lower left corner of the div as expected.

The problem is that when dragging that corner (again, lower left), what moves is the lower-right corner.

The div is deployed at an `absolute` position.

How can I fix this and make the div behave in LTR and RTL as mirror images?

Comment: To those who voted to close this question because it is out of scope, I'd very much appreciate if they substantiate their assessment.

Answer (score 0):

If your div is aligned on the left side of the page, it can't do anything but expand to the right. If you set `float: right`, you can drag the handle and expand it to the left.

I inserted a working example here:

```css
div {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Resizing LTR text.</h1>

<div>
<p>Drag the handle to the left and the div will expand to the left..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Tobias. The problem is that the div cannot be set as `float:right` (or any other direction) because it is open just under a button that may change its position (actually, clicking on the button causes the div to appear).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 class mdiv extends HTMLDivElement  {
        constructor(){
            super();
        }
    // connect component
    connectedCallback() {

        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div style="direction: rtl"> <slot></slot></div>`;
       
    }

    }
    customElements.define("rtl-div", mdiv,{extends:'div'});
```

```css
.kuku {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="kuku" is="rtl-div">kuku</div>

    <div>This is a regular DIV</div>

</body>

</html>
```